# Order of SelectedItem binding and SelectionChanged for ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Currently the binding event of the ListView->SelectedItem in a UWP project is executed before the SelectionChanged event.

Is this order carved in stone? 
If not, how can I ensure that the order stays that way?

Comment: There is no way to change the order of when events are fired

Answer (score 0):

You could pick one, and then dispatch the work that it does back to the application dispatcher with a priority of ApplicationIdle. Then you would be guaranteed that it would occur after the other event has finished.